# Xamarin.Forms Master/Detail edge swipe on iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, master-detail

There is a difference in the swipe gesture to present the master page (drawer menu) on Android and iOS.
On Android it only swipes from screen edge, while on iOS swipe from any point on the screen does it.
The problem with full-screen swipe is that one of my detail pages is a Map and user can't do any left-to-right scrolls because the master detail gesture overrides the map gesture handler.
I worked around it with a simple check

```
IsGestureEnabled = page.DetailPage != MenuItemViewModel.Detail.Map || Device.RuntimePlatform != Device.iOS;
```

Which effectively disables the left menu swipe but what I would really would like to have is a swipe from edge like it happens on Android.

Is there a simple way (i.e. no custom renderers) to do the menu edge swipe on iOS in Xamarin Forms?

Comment: I'm afraid no way to achieve this unless you look for  alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest is to get Mr Gestures plug-in, then on Swipe or Panning event open  menu from the root page

```
//---------------------------------------------------------
public void ShowMenu()
//---------------------------------------------------------
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Root ShowMenu");
    IsPresented = true;
}
```